# Send data from extjs popup window to spring controller

Tags: spring, forms, extjs, controller

I have an extjs popup window with form panel inside and I wanted to know how can I send datas in the form panel to my spring controller ?

```
var formPanel =  {
    xtype       : 'form',
    height      : 125,
    autoScroll  : true,
    id          : 'formpanel',
    defaultType : 'field',
    frame       : true,
    items       : [
        {
            fieldLabel : 'Name'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel : 'Age'
        }
    ]
};

function openIFrame() {
 Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title : 'Import your devices',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [formPanel]
}).show();
```

}

Comment: @zan I added my code, I will create a button "submit" that should send the form but I'm not sure it's possible to send and recover data in my spring controller

Comment: *"Not sure"*? Have you actually *tried* handling the request in a Spring controller? Did it work? If not, why?

Comment: @JeromeCampeaux was my answer halpful for you?

Comment: @JamesSchermann Thank you for reply, I finally use another way to do my stuff ;) Maybe it will help me by the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the form by some selector from controller and then call `getForm().getValues()` method. Method returns an object made by form fields and its values.

Then you can use send this object to the server using `Ext.Ajax.request` method (docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)

Answer (score 0):

You can send request to server with params via this code:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/requestUrl',
    params: {
        param1: data1,
        param2: data2
    },
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        //do something...
        }
    })
```

Also you need to add this code to some listener on your popup, for example in `onButtonClick`

```
function openIFrame() {
 Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title : 'Import your devices',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [formPanel],
    buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    handler: function () {
                       //function which listed above 
                    }
                }

            ]
}).show();
```

And to handle request at BE you need create controller like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestUrl")
public void handler(@RequestParam ("param1") String param1,
                        @RequestParam ("param2") String param2) throws Exception {
      //do something with data
}
```